# Ohm's Law vs. Conservation of Energy Misunderstanding

Tags: energy, ohms-law

I am currently misunderstanding the relation between Ohm's Law and the law for conservation of energy. I am referring to the example (in the book "Foundations of Analog and Digital Electronic Circuits" - Anant Agarwal and Jeffrey H. Lang, page 97):

[image: Example Image from the book]

The example uses \$V^2/R = P\$.
When I check the result (which is 0.5V) against \$V = R\cdot I\$; then I get a voltage that is 2V instead; since \$2\mathrm{mA} \cdot 1k\Omega = 2\mathrm V\$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing, that last step they did was wrong. "In other words, v = 0.5v" Try plugging into the last equation 0.5V

Comment: Indeed you seem to be right. I didn't plug in the variables because I thought some obvious substitution was wrong. This error did stall me for a good 30 minutes. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing at all. The book is wrong.

Just the last line is wrong.. \$0.002v = 0.001v^2\$ divide both sides by \$v\$ and 0.001 and we get \$v = \$\$0.002\over 0.001\$ = 2.

Comment: Ah yes of course, I divided wrongly then, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

2mA thru 1kohm implies 2V and the power is calculated by either: -

\$\dfrac{V^2}{R}\$ = 4mW or

\$I^2R\$ = 4mW

What's the problem?

Ah it's the book (idiots LOL)

Comment: Anant Agarwal (M.I.T. professor, president of edX) isn't an idiot, but the proofreading of that book is not up to snuff.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany do you know him?

Comment: Not personally, but I recommended a few people take the edX MITx 6.002x (undergraduate analog design) course, and have watched all the lectures myself. I've also been following his work with edX since that pioneering offering. It's going to change the face of post-secondary education, possibly beyond recognition, over the coming years.